# jQuery, JSON live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been quite stuck on this problem for like 2 days. I'm trying to make a live name searcher with jQuery and JSON. I've managed to create a 'drop down list' with names from Json table but I have no idea how to make them 'clickable' (for ex. let's search for "Name1", then click it and it should appear in the search box as a value that I can post later to some python script)

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class = 'row'>
    <div class="cold_md-6 m-auto">
      <h3 class="text-center mb-3">
        TEST
      </h3>
      <form action="" class ="form-group" method="POST">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="name_search">
          <div id="match_list">

          </div>
          <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery script:

```
<script>
const search = document.getElementById('name_search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match_list');

const searchName = async searchText => {
  const res = await fetch('../static/json/data.json');
  const names = await res.json();

  let matches = names.filter(test => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
    return test.name.match(regex);
  });

  if (searchText.length === 0){
    matches = [];
    matchList.innerHTML = '';
  }

 outputHtml(matches);
};

const outputHtml = matches => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches
      .map(
        match => `<div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><h4>${match.name}</h4></div>`)
      
      .join('');
    matchList.innerHTML= html;

  }
};

search.addEventListener('input', () => searchName (search.value));
</script>
```

And my JSON table

```
[
    {
      "name":"Name1"
    },
    {
       "name":"Name2"
    },
    {
      "name":"Name3"
    },
    {
      "name":"Name4"
    },
    {
      "name":"Name5"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: One immediate red flag.  You are fetching the contents of the json every time the user generates an `input` event, which will be every time the value of the input changes.  Don't do that.  Start the fetch of the json when the page loads, and use and reuse the results.

Comment: Aside from that, it looks like you already know how to make an event listener on the search element, so what issue or mental block are you hitting with doing the same for the results?